# I is possible to get schedule meeting of the day from Oulook API?

Tags: outlook-restapi

I want to let an employee to see his CEO:s meetings for the current day that the CEO has scheduled in his Outlook calendar.
Is it possible to get current days meetings with Outlook api?

I have read the documenation but cant find anh information on how to only get the current days scheduled meetings.

Answer (score 0):

According to my search, you could use below API:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users('user@companyname.onmicrosoft.com')/findmeetingtimes
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[Can't get all busy times of meeting rooms using the Office365 Calendar API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466839/cant-get-all-busy-times-of-meeting-rooms-using-the-office365-calendar-api)